# Me da fallo al crear el ejecutable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Buena noches he creado un ejecutable con pyinstaller y cuando ejecutó el.exe me sale este error

> failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception:No localization support for language 'eng'
>
> raceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 12, in  File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module File "bbdd.py", line 12, in  File "mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 287, in connect File "mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in init File "mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line

Alguien sabriaque puedo hacer?

Comment: De casualidad te aparece una version mas completa del error? Una linea especifica del código donde falle? O apenas abrir el exe te aparece ese error tal y como está publicado?

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "bbdd.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 287, in connect
  File "mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in __init__
  File "mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line

Comment: Podrías agregarlo en la pregunta formateado por favor? En los comentarios no se ve bien.